# Can't set UIButton highlighted in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I would like to set my `UIButton` highlighted when the user taps a cell, it looked pretty easy, but unfortunately it doesn't work somewhy. I have a custom class for the cell and I'm trying to set it highlighted in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, but when I tap it nothing happens despite  `[self showActionSheet];` has been called every time. I also tried to do it in the `MDTableViewCell.m`'s `setSelected:animated:` method, in this case it highlights every cell's button right after I load the table view. Am I missed something or I do in a wrong place?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MDTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"bookCell"];
    [cell.Buttn setSelected:YES];
    [cell.tButtn setHighlighted:YES];
    [self showActionSheet];

}
```

Comment: You should set up property of your tableViewCell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're dequeuing a new cell that never appears in your UI. If you're trying to get the cell that was tapped on, then use:

```
MDTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This just answers your immediate question, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to highlight the button when you tap on a cell -- it should be highlighted if you tap on it (the button). Also, when you scroll, and the cell is reused, you will see a highlighted button appear in other rows. There are plenty of other answers out there on how to deal with that.

Comment: How can I "get" the proper cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method? Is it possible?

Comment: @gatto, I showed you how to get the proper cell. cellForRowAtIndexPath: gets a reference to the cell that was tapped.